# Used Yarn to install reactstrap but getting "Can't resolve 'reactstrap' "error

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

I installed bootstrap, react-popper and reactstrap using yarn but the page is displaying the following error "Can't resolve 'reactstrap'".

My package.json looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "confusion",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^9.3.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.1.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-popper": "^2.2.3",
    "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.4.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is how I coded the App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand } from 'reactstrap'
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Navbar dark color="primary">
        <div className="container">
          <NavbarBrand href="/">Ristorante Con Fusion</NavbarBrand>
        </div>
      </Navbar>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How can I get the page to display the boostrap navbar? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I got from a classmate that fixed the problem. The app works now.

```
1. Reboot pc.

2.Delete node_modules folder.

3. In terminal run command 'yarn cache clean'

4. Delete 'package-lock.json', 'yarn.lock' files but keep "package.json'

5. In terminal run command 'yarn install'

6. In terminal run command 'yarn start'
```